# Scrollview like in Google+ feed detail

Tags: android, layout, scrollview, google-plus

I want to do `ScrollView` where the bottom view with information data when scrolling overlaps photo above (photo remains in the same place), as well as in google+ application in feed detail. Sorry for bad English. Thanks

Image what I want:

[When detail loaded](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qfbbmnlamd4gt61/Screenshot_2012-08-09-16-52-01.png) 
[When srolling](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qvajjuqhyi0052r/Screenshot_2012-08-09-16-49-21.png)

Comment: do you want the view below the image to overlap the image when you scroll ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a an `ImageView` in the background for your top image and then put a `ScrollView` on top of it, either using `RelativeLayout` or `FrameLayout`. Then inside the `ScrollView` you could use a vertical `LinearLayout` and either use a `Space` as the first item in the list and make it the same size as the `ImageView`, or you could simply set the margin of the first item to have a top margin that is the same size as the `ImageView`.